# ARCore - Use Existing Activity as a Renderable

Tags: android, android-studio, arcore

Is there anyway to use an existing activity as a renderable in AR core? I understand I can just set the layout to be the layout of the renderable. However, I have a fragment w/in the activity and would also like the same capabilities as the activity (click, etc)

For example, I have an activity that already exists in my app. However, now I want to show the content of the activity in AR mode so I wanted to make a renderable for this activity.